# Noise mitigation in +/-5mV instrumentation amplifier?

Tags: noise, differential, instrumentation-amplifier

I am building a differential amplifier to boost a 0-5mV (delta) signal off a load cell wheatstone bridge.

In simulation, the design works here (falstad):
[image]

(for those who have not used falstad circuit simulator, the "2.53V" line are just voltage readings).

However, when factoring ambient noise, as observed in experimentation, the amplifier is essentially useless. I built the circuit in our lab yesterday to confirm this and unfortunately forgot to capture any scope screenshots. However, it appears that the noise off the wheatstone bridge is ***not*** from any direct source (eg 60Hz).

Apart from keeping wires short and ensuring consistent grounding, what else can I do to get rid of this noise? The very small delta of 5mV is observable on the scope when loading the load cell via an "up and down" translation on the scope. However, the channel itself has about +/-50mV of noise in the signal.

Any advice?

*EDIT* And I should finally add in case it is not clear, this is a DC circuit. Thus, frequency is ideally <1Hz.

Comment: Are you applying an ideal voltage source of 2.5V and getting a reading of 2.53V? That would make me suspicious of the simulation.

Comment: There are 22 bit ADCs with 5 volt rails, and excellent CMRR, with 5 to 15 conversions per second. Use the differential inputs.

Comment: @Elliot The absolute voltage off the wheatstone bridge is 2.528V (no stress) to 2.531V (fully stressed). The delta is approximately 5mV full-swing.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Ah yes, results have been confirmed using the off-shelf HX711 ADC for strain gauges. The system our team is constructing is going to used for teaching purposes. It is an "exploded" ADC itself used to demonstrate individual components within off-shelf ADCs. Thus, this issue arises.

Comment: Try to add a capacitor e.g. 50pF in parallel with the 1.6MOhm feedback resistor.

Comment: The circuit you have up is NOT an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: Which opamp? Many modern MOS opamps add lots of 1/f noise. Choose carefully.

Comment: You've got some kind of grounding/shielding problem. I doubt changing the op-amp will help. You can add low pass filtering and improve grounding.

Comment: @Spehro, I am connected directly to mains ground via lab power supply and <5cm cables. Can't be grounded much better than that unless I PCB the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to buy the right IC for the job.  You need an instrumentation amplifier -- or at the very least, a specialized differential amplifier on a chip, with both the positive and negative inputs having the same gain.

Assuming your 60Hz noise is uniformly present on both inputs, this would be *common mode* noise.  Thus, you need a circuit with a good Common Mode Rejection Ratio (CMRR). Your circuit does not have that, by design, as you have different gains for the positive and negative inputs.  Even if the inputs had the same gain, it is still fairly difficult to construct circuits with good CMRR's because of tolerances on resistors, but it is very easy to buy them.

I suggest you confirm this for yourself in sim, by putting a 60Hz voltage source on both inputs.

Comment: Makes sense. I have not personally dealt with small signal (<100mV) system design. Would the TI INA821 be an appropriate selection for this design? Instrumentation amplifier with a high >100dB CMRR.

Comment: @Matt probably more than good enough, if you can work w/ the SOIC package.  Pick up a 2.5V precision voltage reference, as well, for the reference pin.

Answer (score 1):

A real instrumentation Op. Amp. is really the simplest option.

If you *have* to use general purpose amplifiers (which, by the way, you did not mention) the best option would be to implement an instrumentation amplifier with two stages, with the gain divided among them. That way it would be easier to compensate for DC offset at the inputs.

Comment: I placed an order for a proper 2-stage instrumentation amplifier. I would like to know, what is your idea for a strategy of DC-offset compensation at the inputs? Because once it arrives, that will be an issue.

Comment: Great. Please kindly provide a full schematic with the INA part number if you still need advice when implementing it. The compensation I meant was referring to the second option, if you had decided to _implement_ an instrumentation amplifier using conventional Amp. Ops.